# Still running python 2.7 when running python in windows 10 command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

When I'm running Flask it runs python 2.7, I want it to run on python 3.6.

When I type into the command prompt:

```
python
```

it shows it is running python 2.7

So when I type into the command prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

[it shows that python 3.6 is on the top of the variable list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3XHU.jpg)

SO when the path to 3.6 is on top of the list it should automatically run flask in python 3.6 right?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PATH` is misconfigured, it should only contains path to **folders** containing binaries, not path to the binary itself

You should change `C:\Python36-32\python.exe` to `C:\Python36-32`

Comment: Sort of solved it for me. When I run python in my command line now it runs python 3.6, but when I run sys.executable in my flask application it still prints the path to python 2.7. any way to solve this?